# can't install libvorbis on centos 7, fatal error: ogg/ogg.h: No such file or directory

Tags: ffmpeg, centos7

Hello I've been trying to install FFmpeg with some libraries using this tutorial
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos?version=85

using this command to install the libvorbis

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
curl -O -L http://downloads.xiph.org/releases/vorbis/libvorbis-1.3.5.tar.gz
tar xzvf libvorbis-1.3.5.tar.gz
cd libvorbis-1.3.5
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --with-ogg="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared
make
make install
```

i get this error with command make

```
    ../include/vorbis/codec.h:26:21: fatal error: ogg/ogg.h: No such file or directory
     #include <ogg/ogg.h>
compilation terminated.
```

and when i install ffmpeg i get this error

```
ERROR: vorbis not found using pkg-config
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

libvorbis requires libogg. This is mentioned in the guide you followed. So compile libogg first:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
curl -O -L https://downloads.xiph.org/releases/ogg/libogg-1.3.4.tar.gz
tar xzvf libogg-1.3.4.tar.gz
cd libogg-1.3.4
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared
make
make install
```

Then compile libvorbis:

```
cd ~/ffmpeg_sources
curl -O -L https://downloads.xiph.org/releases/vorbis/libvorbis-1.3.6.tar.gz
tar xzvf libvorbis-1.3.6.tar.gz
cd libvorbis-1.3.6
./configure --prefix="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --with-ogg="$HOME/ffmpeg_build" --disable-shared
make
make install
```

Note that libogg is currently at version 1.3.4 and libvorbis is at 1.3.6. You are following an old revision of the guide so you were attempting to install libvorbis 1.3.5.